# Как правильно вызвать BAT файл в Python?

Tags: python, windows, bat, gradle

У меня есть скрипт на Python, который должен выполнить .bat файл с параметром.

> D:\YandexDisc\AndroidApps\Build_DrawProjects\DrawOwls\gradlew.bat
>   assembleRelease

Из консоли всё работает нормально, но при разных способов запуска BAT файла из Python

> D:\YandexDisc\Python

Питон пытается вызвать BAT файл из своей папки. По крайней мере, Gradle ругается, что assembleRelease не найден в проекте Python

> - What went wrong: Task 'assembleRelease' not found in root project 'Python'.

Пробовал:

```
p = Popen('cmd.exe /k start '+'D:\YandexDisc\AndroidApps\Build_DrawProjects\DrawOwls\gradlew.bat assembleRelease')
p = subprocess.Popen('D:\\YandexDisc\\AndroidApps\\Build_DrawProjects\\DrawOwls\\gradlew.bat assembleRelease', creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
p = subprocess.Popen('D:\YandexDisc\AndroidApps\Build_DrawProjects\DrawOwls\gradlew.bat assembleRelease', creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
os.system("D:\YandexDisc\AndroidApps\Build_DrawProjects\DrawOwls\gradlew.bat assembleRelease")
os.system("D:\YandexDisc\AndroidApps\Build_DrawProjects\DrawOwls\gradlew.bat assembleRelease")
call("D:\YandexDisc\AndroidApps\Build_DrawProjects\DrawOwls\gradlew.bat assembleRelease")
```

Я проверил. Получается, что текущая директория это директория проекта и при запуске gradlew.bat работает с текущей директорией. То есть, мне нужно указать директорию при запуске бат файла.

Comment: А так? `os.system("D:\\YandexDisc\\AndroidApps\\Build_DrawProjects\\DrawOwls\\gradlew.bat assembleRelease")`

Comment: * What went wrong:
Task 'assembleRelease' not found in root project 'Python'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно было указать cwd

```
p = subprocess.Popen('D:\YandexDisc\AndroidApps\Build_DrawProjects\DrawOwls\gradlew.bat assembleRelease', cwd='D:\YandexDisc\AndroidApps\Build_DrawProjects\DrawOwls', creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
```

Comment: закройте вопрос, поставив галочку напротив ответа